# How to distinguish an empty list from a list of one empty parameter in Swagger?

Tags: arrays, string, swagger, specifications

I am implementing a in-house code generator that implements Swagger 2.0 (OpenAPI).

I am facing an ambiguity that I find impossible to resolve from reading the specifications.

Say we have an `array` type of `strings` (be it in `path` or `query`, it's the same thing here), which is comma separated.

- A list of two elements is represented as: `a,b`
- A list of one element is represented as: `a`
- An empty list is represented as:
- A list of two empty elements is represented as : `,`
- A list of one empty element is represented as :

Clearly, having the same representation for an *empty list* and a *list of one empty element* is a problem. Of course, I could decide that a list of one empty element is represented as `,` (Python does that for it's tuples) but then how should I represent a list of two empty elements ?

Of course in the case of the query parameter, I can just solve the ambiguity with the absence of the parameter itself (but that does not solve the problem for `path` parameters, nor does it give me any guarantee about what other implementations do).

Anyway, I don't want to "decide" anything but rather implement the spec. to maximize interoperability. However, I can't find any authoritative source as to how to handle that situation.

Are empty strings forbidden in swagger strings arrays ? Should I ignore them ? Consider those lists invalid ?

In short: what should I do in those cases ?

Comment: which version of swagger are you using? < 2.5 ?

Comment: @pvpkiran Given that the current highest version is 2.0 (from [here](http://swagger.io/specification/)) I guess my answer is "yes, version 2.0".

Comment: upgrade  to latest swagger version which 2.6.1 and check

Comment: @pvpkiran Are you talking about `swagger-codegen` or the Swagger specification ? I implement my own code-generator so I'm not sure which version you are talking about.